# v8 getHeapShot causes jest to hang indefinitetly

Tags: typescript, jestjs, memory-leaks, heap-memory, v8

Currently, I have a memory leak in my code and I'm trying to debug it by creating a heap snapshot using Nodes v8 library. I'm creating an endpoint in typescript using express which I can call and it should return a JSON object that can be written to a file and imported into chrome dev tools.

However, when I run my jest test to test the endpoint it hangs indefinitely.
I'm currently calling

```
jest --runInBand InfoController.test.ts
```

InfoController.ts

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { getHeapSnapshot } from 'v8';
import { constants } from 'http2';

export const InfoController = (): Router => {
  const router = Router();
  router.get('/heapdump', (_, res) => {
    console.log('requesting heap snapshot')
    const heapShot = getHeapSnapshot();
    console.log('heap');
    let data = '';
    heapShot.on('readable', () => {
      const chunk = heapShot.read();
      while (chunk !== null) {
        data += chunk;
      }
    });

    heapShot.on('end', () => res.status(constants.HTTP_STATUS_OK).json(JSON.parse(data)));
  });

  return router;
};
```

InfoController.test.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import { constants as httpConstants } from 'http2';
import Request from 'supertest';
import { InfoController } from './InfoController';

describe(' InfoController', () => {
  describe('GET /heapdump', () => {
    test('should be able to retrieve a v8 heapdump of the service', async () => {
      const controller = InfoController();

      const app = express();
      app.use(express.json());
      app.use(controller);

      const result = await Request(app).get('/heapdump').expect(httpConstants.HTTP_STATUS_OK);
      console.log(result.body);
    });
  });
});
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  bail: true,
  verbose: true,
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  collectCoverage: false,
  testMatch: ['**/**/*.test.ts'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/build/'],
  collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/**', '!<rootDir>/src/index.ts'],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules', '<rootDir>/__tests__'],
  globalSetup: '<rootDir>/__tests__/global/setup.ts',
};
```

This is the output I'm getting

```
$ jest --runInBand src/http/controllers/InfoController.test.ts
console.log
    requesting heap snapshot

      at src/http/controllers/InfoController.ts:8:13


 RUNS  src/http/controllers/InfoController.test.ts
```

After this, it just hangs and never completes ????

Answer (score 0):

Consider this snippet at the center of your code:

```
      const chunk = heapShot.read();
      while (chunk !== null) {
        data += chunk;
      }
```

If `chunk` is ever non-null (which is pretty much guaranteed to happen), that will loop forever (or, well, at least until `data` becomes so big that the whole process will crash with OOM).

The [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable) shows one possibility how to modify the snippet to make it work:

```
  let chunk;
  while ((chunk = heapShot.read()) !== null) {
    data += chunk;
  }
```